# Change property of ListViewItem in ListView by Index - Windows 10 Universal

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10, windows-10-universal

I want to change the color of a `ListViewItem` in a `ListView` by it´s index.
But when I do this, I get a `NullReferenceException`:

```
Brush brush = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Green);
(baustellenListView.Items.ElementAt(i) as ListViewItem).Foreground = brush;
```

`baustellenListView` is the name of the `ListView`.

Thank you for help!

Comment: Did you debug _what_ is `null`? Is it the `baustellenListView`? Or does `ElementAt(i)` return `null` or something that is not a `ListViewItem` (so `as` returns `null`)?

Comment: +  Windows.UI.Colors.Green {#FF008000} Windows.UI.Color
+  baustellenListView.Items {Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ItemCollection} Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ItemCollection
+  brush {Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.SolidColorBrush} Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Brush {Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.SolidColorBrush}
  i 1 int
+  this {SchlachterFliesen.Baustelle} SchlachterFliesen.Baustelle

Comment: i have no idea what should be null here

Comment: baustellenListView is definitely not null and all items are ListViewItems

Comment: lol, this is no duplicate. This is a special case -.-

Comment: There are very rarely really special cases to that. The ways how to debug and investigate the reasons for a `NullReferenceException` are all explained in the linked question. And there is nothing else we/you can do except investigating. From the code you posted, there are only the options I mentioned above. I really think `baustellenListView.Items` does contain the data objects, not `ListViewItem` instances. So the `as` operator returns `null`. Please _debug_ and check the type of objects in `baustellenListView.Items`.

Comment: Ok, it´s the data objects. But how do I get the ListViewItems itself?

Comment: Oh, wir können auch Deutsch schreiben. :)

Comment: Also Frage ist eigentlich wie komme ich an die ListViewItem Objekte aus der ListView ran. Items gibt nur die Daten Objekte.

Comment: It seems this question is really "How do I get an item in a list and change it's color?" Just because the way they've tried resulted in a NullReferenceException and explaining what that is will only show the problem with the OPs code, not how to solve their actual problem.

Comment: Yes. My question is indeed how to get an Item out of the ListView with an index and change its color. With ListView.Items I only get the data objects not the items. Could anyone please tell me how to get the actual items? Thank you so much